# Pygame version with python 3.6

Tags: pygame

I have python 3.6 on my windows, which pygame should I download? I have tried multiple downloads and they do not work. Please help!

Comment: Please add what versions you have tried and what errors are you getting

Answer (score 4):

The best way to install Pygame on Windows is to enter this in the command line:

```
py -3.6 -m pip install pygame
```

This will install Pygame specifically for version 3.6 (just in case you have other Python versions that come first in your PATH variable).

Answer (score 0):

This one should work: http://pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.1.win32-py2.6.msi
(its the only one for python 2.6 on windows) if it doesn't you will probably have to downgrade to 32x python :(

Comment: Shouldn't that be 3.6 instead of 2.6?

Comment: Oh yeah oops :P. Looks like there isnt a version on their website for 3.6... sorry for not being any help.