# How to install pygame on python 3.4.4 using pip

Tags: python, pygame

i am entering

```
pip install pygame
```

into cmd and what is retruned is

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

i am running windows 10 64 bit and python 3.4.4 64 bit

Comment: [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42663743/6220679), just replace `3.6` with `3.4`. BTW, why don't you use the latest Python version?

Comment: because i am using pyscripter which i have always used and it only supports 3.4.4:)

Comment: and i have tried it using 3.6 and it didnt work aswell was getting the same error

Comment: Did you enter `py -3.4 -m pip install pygame`?

Comment: that got me so far but then i got Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-fzmrdx00\pygame

Comment: and when i try and upgrade the pip module it says python is not recognized

Comment: Also, you most likely see the error `'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command` because the Scripts directory wasn't added to your PATH variable (you have to click a checkmark during the installation of Python). You can add it manually if you just want to enter `pip` in the command-line.

Comment: just got it to work for some reason it did not seam to like it when i used python but when i used py it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entering `py -3.4 -m pip install pygame` in the command-line is the least error prone way to install pygame on Windows (replace `3.4` by your specific Python version).

That is because you have to click a [checkmark](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#installation-steps) during the installation to add Python to the PATH and can't enter `python` in the command-line if you forget it and the `/Scripts` directory also has to be added to the PATH, otherwise you can't enter `pip`. But using the Python launcher `py -3` or `py -3.4` and running pip as a module `-m pip` usually works.

Answer (score -1):

First install pip

```
python get-pip.py
```

Add your python C:\Pythonx\Scripts to the system path

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\pythonx\Scripts
```

then run

```
pip install pygame
```

Comment: pip is already install beacuse it comes with python doesnt it? and what do you mean by add it to the path?

Comment: In CMD set this path (pythonx -- replace it with your python folder name)

`set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\pythonx\Scripts `