# How To Install Pygame 1.9.3 for python 3.6

Tags: python, windows, pygame, pip, python-wheel

Here's my problem: I need to install pygame 1.9.3 for python 3.6 for a homework assignment but I have tried almost every possible thing to install it but to no avail I still can't install it. When I try to pip install I get this error:

```
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip install wheel
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Here's the install picture:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you installed `pip`?

Comment: What OS are you using? Also here are some relevant reading: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/

Comment: This sounds really stupid but how do I? I probably haven't.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12476379/3282436 Instructions should be similar for non-Windows operating systems.

Comment: I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Although, the link that I posted says that `pip` should be included with Python 3 v3.4 and greater.  You have installed Python, right?

Comment: Yes, I have installed Python and I have been using it since about may of this year.

Comment: Now I am getting this:

Comment: PS C:\Users\1234> python get-pip.py
python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python get-pip.py
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Command

Comment: Sorry I'm in really over my head...

Comment: Have you [tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42663743/6220679) as well?

Comment: Thank you so much skrx! It worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this as well? – skrx 10 hours ago

Thanks to skrx all I had to do is type this in:

py -3.6 -m pip install pygame

Thank you so much now I can go on with my school work!