# Error installing pygame-1.9.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pygame, pip

When I am trying to install this version of pygame (pygame-1.9.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64), it gives me this error:

```
C:\Users\Luke>pip install pygame-1.9.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64
Collecting pygame-1.9.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame-1.9.3-cp37-
cp37m-win_amd64 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pygame-1.9.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64
```

I have also tried pygame-1.9.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64

Thank you for your help!

Comment: And what about `pip install pygame` or, if you need 1.9.3 specifically, `pip install pygame==1.9.3`?

Comment: First don't use Python 3.7, it's still an alpha version. Install Python 3.6 and then [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42663743/6220679).

Comment: Oh, that might be the problem. I have 3.6, but didn't know cp37m stood for something. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are mixing things...

either you use pip for download/install, for that case

```
pip install pygame
```

should do (although the instruction on their website has a slightly different line).

or you manually download a wheel (.whl) with correct binaries for your OS and Python install, for this case the filenames looks something like you have written, but you have no file extension in your line in the question.

I'm not a pip expert, but it looks like you are via pip asking for a package that has the long name, and that it cannot find.

If you manually want to download the right wheel you can either find that on pypi, or you can do a websearch for "windows binaries pygame" and you should find something that works.

It was a while since I tried installing pygame, but I do remember that it was working on the first go last time I tried, and that it was straightforward to get it installed.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've had a problem with pip before, and I was just looking around and reading about people with similar problems, so thats where I got it from. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

"you have no file extension in your line in the question."
ahed87, let me know to include the file ext, in my case it was the same file in question; Fixed my issue by adding (.whl) at the end of the file.