# pygame looks like a filename, but the file does not exist

Tags: python, pygame

I decided to try to install pygame and have run into this problem:

```
Requirement 'pygame-1.9.3-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
pygame-1.9.3-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Everything worked up till this point and I'm so close to installing pygame.   Also this is the thing that I typed:

```
pip install pygame-1.9.3-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
```

Comment: How are you installing? Via `pip`?

Comment: I think so but then i am very new to pygame

Comment: also i appreciate how quick it is to get some help

Comment: On what python version are you? (`pip --version`)

Comment: Also, on what OS are you? Windows, 32bit?

Comment: oh I'm using windows

Comment: If your are on windows 64bit (as you probably are) you have to find a wheel which ends in win64 and not win32

Comment: Right I will do that I will probably work because I didn't try that.

Comment: C:\>pip install pygame-1.9.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement 'pygame-1.9.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
pygame-1.9.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: is this what you meant? or am I just getting really confused.

Comment: Check out if this works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42663743/6220679

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally use a tool like pip to install wheels. Leave it to the tool to discover and download the file if this is for a project hosted on PyPI.
For this to work, you do need to install the wheel package:

```
Pip install wheel
```

You can then tell pip to install the project (and it'll download the wheel if available), or the wheel file directly:

```
pip install project_name  # discover, download and install
pip install wheel_file.whl  # directly install the wheel
```

The wheel module, once installed, also is runnable from the command line, you can use this to install already-downloaded wheels:
`python -m wheel install wheel_file.whl`
Also see the wheel project documentation.