# Can't install 64-bit Pygame in Python

Tags: python, pygame, 64-bit

It came to my attention that 64-bit pygame does not install automatically on python 3(but I guess 32-bit does, I digress) and you have to do it by hand, however, after following instructions from this site:

https://www.webucator.com/blog/2015/03/installing-the-windows-64-bit-version-of-pygame/

...to install pip and wheel and make them the most updated versions of themselves.

I changed the cmd directory to the one I kept the pygame '64-bit Python 3.6 version' .whl file located within and I and then typed "pip install pygame-1.9.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl" into my command prompt, and the error message in red said:

"pygame-1.9.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Does anyone know where I went wrong? I am on windows 7 Python is 3.6.5:f59c0932b4, pygame .whl file is pygame-1.9.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whln, it upgraded to wheel 10 and deleted wheel 9 if that helps.

Comment: Dont use wheels, just use `pip install pygame`.

Comment: The error probably occurs because the bitness of your Python version and the pygame wheel don't match. Better use pip to install pygame, since it will automatically install the correct version. This is the least error prone way to install pygame in Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42663743/6220679